# Azure Terrafy facing issue in Error: retrieving Subnet Service Endpoint Storage Policy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I am trying to export the existing resources in Azure by using the Azure Terrafy when am doing this am facing with the below error

Error: retrieving Subnet Service Endpoint Storage Policy "_e41f87a2_mi_xxx" (Resource Group "xxxx"):
network.ServiceEndpointPoliciesClient#Get: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=200 -- Original Error: Error occurred unmarshalling JSON

- Error = 'json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field ServiceEndpointPolicyPropertiesFormat.contextualServiceEndpointPolicies of type
  "id":
  "/subscriptions/4xxxx/resourceGroups/xx/providers/Microsoft.Network/serviceEndpointPolicies/*e41xxx*

Error: retrieving Subnet Service Endpoint Storage Policy network.ServiceEndpointPoliciesClient#Get: Failure responding to request: Error = 'json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field ServiceEndpointPolicyPropertiesFormat.contextualServiceEndpointPolicies of type

Hello Team ,

I am trying to export the existing resources in Azure by using the Azure Terrafy when am doing this am facing with the below error
Error: retrieving Subnet Service Endpoint Storage Policy "_e41f87a2_mi_xxx" (Resource Group "xxxx"):
network.ServiceEndpointPoliciesClient#Get: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=200 -- Original Error: Error occurred unmarshalling JSON

- Error = 'json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field ServiceEndpointPolicyPropertiesFormat.contextualServiceEndpointPolicies of type
  "id":
  "/subscriptions/4xxxx/resourceGroups/xx/providers/Microsoft.Network/serviceEndpointPolicies/*e41xxx*

Error: retrieving Subnet Service Endpoint Storage Policy network.ServiceEndpointPoliciesClient#Get: Failure responding to request: Error = 'json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field ServiceEndpointPolicyPropertiesFormat.contextualServiceEndpointPolicies of type

Comment: Hi there, You are using `Azure DevOps` tag to reach out to members in this subcommunity. May I assume are you using Azure DevOps Pipeline to automate the Azure Terrafy workflow? Have you tried the `aztfy` command via local PowerShell? It will help isolate the issue. Thx.